# Store Exception after upgrade

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I get this after updating from 2.1 to 2.2

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'block', attribute 'class': [facet 'pattern'] The value '\\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template' is not accepted by the pattern '[A-Z][_a-zA-Z\d]*(\\[A-Z][_a-zA-Z\d]*)*'.
Line: 687

Element 'block', attribute 'class': '\\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'blockClassType'.
Line: 687


Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'block', attribute 'class': [facet 'pattern'] The value '\\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template' is not accepted by the pattern '[A-Z][_a-zA-Z\d]*(\\[A-Z][_a-zA-Z\d]*)*'.
Line: 687

Element 'block', attribute 'class': '\\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'blockClassType'.
Line: 687
```

I already read topic on github with same problem but idk what I supposed to do to fix this.

Now I fixed broken class in one of files in app/code
And get the "Attribute layout redefined" with checkout_index_index.xml 
I deleted this file and completely get this:

```
Element 'move', attribute 'name': The attribute 'name' is not allowed.
Line: 687

Element 'remove': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( block, container, referenceBlock, referenceContainer, uiComponent ).
Line: 723
```

Also code of my chekout_index_index.xml because i delete, not fix it

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="empty" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="page.messages" remove="true" />
        <move element="logo" destination="checkout.header.wrapper" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue remove "\" from start of class names

Comment: Okay I was looking for a broken class in theme files and it was in modules directory (app/code)
Now I'm getting error "Attribute layout redefined" with checkout_index_index.xml
When i delete this xml - I get errors with move remove  classes:
Element 'move', attribute 'name': The attribute 'name' is not allowed.
Line: 687

Element 'remove': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( block, container, referenceBlock, referenceContainer, uiComponent ).
Line: 723

Comment: Remove name attribute form move nodes

Comment: If i understand you right, I should change all constructions looks like this:
<move element="navigation.sections" name="topmenu" as="catalog.topnav" destination="custom-menu" />
to 
<move element="navigation.sections"  destination="custom-menu" /> ?